# I Can't connect to wifi (Ubuntu focal fosa)

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I bought a new PC. Installed Ubuntu focal fosa latest version and I can't connect to my router, even though I have the correct password.

Yesterday I tweaked with it a little bit (I remember setting MAC address as permanent) and it connected. I reinstalled network-manager, sudo apt-get update/upgrade etc. Shut it off.

Today I'm seeing exactly the same thing. Can't connect. I'm writing this having connected via a bluetooth adapter on my PC from my smartphone to the same router. It sees the router, but it cannot connect: activation of network connection failed.

I've tried everything now, deleted the mac address field, put it stable, permanent, random, etc.IPV6 automatic and automatic DHCP only and so on.

What can be the problem?

I thought of installing this one, though it's a whole procedure, but it's already outdated (see kernel support).
https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/download/tl-wn823n/#Driver

It's not a driver thing, the stick sees everything. It's the wifi stick / network-manager sending something wrong and the router blocks it.

It also can't connect to **no password networks** (I haven't tweaked anything on this one), so it's the network manager.

edit: Found that the network manager doesn't support properly the tp-link wifi stick 'TL-WN823N N300'. I just changed wifi stick and it works like a charm. Unfortunately I'm now with my old one, which is very big and ugly.

Comment: What is "setting MAC address as permanent"?

Comment: In the network manager interface, the one that sees the wifis, you select the wifi you have tried to connect to or connected to by clicking the settings icon, then in the tab 'Identity' and in its field 'Cloned Address', there is a drop-down list with Preserve, Permanent, Random, Stable. The MAC adress and cloned address fields are usually empty. There are not many other options one can weak with..